# Run javascript ad script at runtime

Tags: javascript

How can I insert a third-party ad script (javascript) into an empty div using jquery/javascript.
The issue is I get the ad script via ajax.

```
<!-- begin ad tag (tile=1.....) -->
<script language="javascript"><!--
document.write('<scr'+'ipt language="javascript1.1" src="http://adserver.adtechus.com/addyn/3.0/5361.1/2130212/0/4417/ADTECH;loc=100;target=_blank;key=3104;grp=[group];misc='+new Date().getTime()+'"></scri'+'pt>');
//-->
</script><noscript><a href="http://adserver.adtechus.com/adlink/3.0/5361.1/2130212/0/4417/ADTECH;loc=300;key=3104;grp=[group]" target="_blank"><img src="http://adserver.adtechus.com/adserv/3.0/5361.1/2130212/0/4417/ADTECH;loc=300;key=3104;grp=[group]" border="0" width="670" height="200"></a></noscript>
<!-- End of JavaScript Tag -->
```

The issue is the page load that when I attempt to load it into the empty div (inline_ad_one):
inlinead_1_code is a variable holding the ad data.

```
$("#inline_ad_one").html(inlinead_1_code);
```

it loads the page them jumps to a new page containing only the served ad.
How can I get it to load into the empty div?

Comment: Thanks for looking: [http://test.mypackage.com.au/house-land/vic/point-cook/](http://test.mypackage.com.au/house-land/vic/point-cook/)

Answer (score 0):

Place the advert in a separate HTML file and use something like:

```
$('.adcontainer').load('advert.html');
```

to load the file into the div.

Because you are using `document.write`, I think the page is being overwritten by that line (though I've never used document.write so I'm not 100% on that).